# Finding shortest path in non-weighted graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

During a course in University concerning graph theory, we were talking about finding shortest paths thus Dijkstra's algorithm came up, at that point I should mention that the edges of the graph were weighted, with weights>0. Then the professor asked how we could find the shortest path if the edges weren't weighted, I thought the same algorithm would do, since the edges had the "same" non-negative weight. But he suggested BFS. Is this true? wouldn't Dijkstra work correct? I'm not questing BFS finding the path but since it is exhaustive I thought maybe it would be better to avoid it.

Comment: If I am not wrong, Dijkstra's algorithm reduces to BFS if all the weights of edges are equal in length.

Comment: Oh I thought that could be a possibility wasn't sure though. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijsktra worked fine for me even with  non-wighted graphs. Every connection just has weight 1.

Comment: yeah that was my first hunch too